# jQuery $.each vs for loop through object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following code to return a Chinese word's English translation on hover.

```
//return Chinese/English words from database
$("#npc_dialog span").on("mouseover", function() {
    var word = $(this).text();
    $("#currentWord").text(parseHoveredText(word));
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#currentWord").empty();
});
```

It works with a for loop:

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
    for (vocab in hoveredWords) {
        if(word.toLowerCase() === vocab) {
            return hoveredWords[vocab];
        }
    }
};
```

But does not if I use jQuery `$.each`.

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
    $.each(hoveredWords, function(key, value) {
        if(word.toLowerCase() === key) {
            return value;
        }
    });
};
```

---

In both cases, the `console.log()` of the returned value yields the same value. Why doesn't the jQuery work?

In the for loop:

`console.log(hoveredWords[vocab]);` gives: `You`

In the jQuery $.each:

`console.log(value);` gives: `You`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because you have a anonymous function, when you return the `value` it is from the each callback function not from the `parseHoveredText` method.

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
    var val;
    $.each(hoveredWords, function(key, value) {
        if(word.toLowerCase() === key) {
            val =value;
            //return false to prevent any further iterations
            return false;
        }
    });
    return val;
};
```

but from the looks of it, it should be as simple as

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
    return hoveredWords[word.toLowerCase()];
};
```

Comment: Awesome. The simplified function works perfectly. How is it that `return hoveredWords[word.toLowerCase()];` is able to find the word I'm looking for? Is the loop assumed?

Comment: `hoveredWords` is a object which contains key value pairs.... so you can use [member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to fetch the value

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement in each will end the `each` loop instead of returning value from function. You need to return `false` to finish the for loop instead of returning the value. You should assign value to some variable (*that is accessible out the each block*) in each loop before returning from `each` function and return that value from function `parseHoveredText`

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
    var result = "";
    $.each(hoveredWords, function(key, value) {
        if(word.toLowerCase() === key) {
            result = value;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

Comment: You need to `return false` to make the loop stop.